# Getting error in google api client with id 0 when used in alertdialog

Tags: android, google-maps, android-alertdialog

I am using google's auto location to fetch the location which i have given in the alert dialog box when i opened the dialog for the first time everything works fine but when i close the dialog box and open the dialog box again it shows me an error stating **Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0** even i have tried changing enableautomanage and added the onstart and onpause method but nothing works .

Can anyone tell me why it occurs and how can i overcome this error when using it in alertdialog box.

code:

```
 final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Activity_AddFastEntryDaybook.this);
    final View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_newfarmer, null);
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity_AddFastEntryDaybook.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    mlayout = promptView.findViewById(R.id.relative_view_layout);
    final TextInputLayout ti_farmername = (TextInputLayout) promptView.findViewById(R.id.inputfarname);
    final TextInputLayout ti_farmermobno = (TextInputLayout) promptView.findViewById(R.id.inputfarmobno);
    final TextInputLayout ti_farmerlocation = (TextInputLayout) promptView.findViewById(R.id.inputfarmlocation);
    edt_farmername = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.farmername);
    edt_farmermobno = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.farmermobileno);
    final ImageView importcontacts = (ImageView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.img_importcontacts);
    final ImageView btnsave = (ImageView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.img_save);
    final AutoCompleteTextView actv_farmerlocation = (AutoCompleteTextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.farmerlocation);
    // checkconnection();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Activity_AddFastEntryDaybook.this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
    actv_farmerlocation.setThreshold(1);
    actv_farmerlocation.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
    mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW, null);
    actv_farmerlocation.setDropDownWidth(-1);
    actv_farmerlocation.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);

    importcontacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            farmercontacts();
        }
    });
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String farmer_name = edt_farmername.getText().toString();
            String farmer_mobno = edt_farmermobno.getText().toString();
            String farmer_location = actv_farmerlocation.getText().toString();
            if (farmer_name.length() == 0) {
                edt_farmername.setError("Enter Name");
            } else if (farmer_mobno.length() == 0) {
                edt_farmermobno.setError("MobileNo");
            } else if ((farmer_mobno.length() > 10) && (farmer_mobno.startsWith("6") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("5") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("4") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("3")
                    || farmer_mobno.startsWith("2") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("1") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("0") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("*") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("#") || farmer_mobno.endsWith("*") || farmer_mobno.endsWith("#"))) {
                edt_farmermobno.setError("enter a valid mobile no");
            } else if ((farmer_mobno.length() == 10) && (farmer_mobno.startsWith("6") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("5") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("4") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("3") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("2") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("1") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("0") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("*") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("#") || farmer_mobno.endsWith("*") || farmer_mobno.endsWith("#"))) {
                edt_farmermobno.setError("Invalid mobile no");
            } else if ((farmer_mobno.length() < 10) && farmer_mobno.startsWith("6") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("5") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("4") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("3")
                    || farmer_mobno.startsWith("2") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("1") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("0") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("*") || farmer_mobno.startsWith("#") || farmer_mobno.endsWith("*") || farmer_mobno.endsWith("#")) {
                edt_farmermobno.setError("enter a valid mobile no");

            } else if (farmer_location.length() == 0) {
                actv_farmerlocation.setError("Location");
            } else {
                edt_farmername.setError(null);
                edt_farmermobno.setError(null);
                actv_farmerlocation.setError(null);
                databasehandler.insertFarmer(farmer_name, farmer_mobno, farmer_location);
                alert.dismiss();
                myAdapterfarmer.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
    alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpk.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zzf(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at codingtown.coconut.daybook.activity.Activity_AddFastEntryDaybook.addnewfarmer(Activity_AddFastEntryDaybook.java:325)
                                                                    at codingtown.coconut.daybook.activity.Activity_AddFastEntryDaybook.access$000(Activity_AddFastEntryDaybook.java:74)
                                                                    at codingtown.coconut.daybook.activity.Activity_AddFastEntryDaybook$5.onClick(Activity_AddFastEntryDaybook.java:265)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not from alertdialog ,You may try this by adding code

` mGoogleApiClient .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)

Comment: I have done that already but still i am getting the same error

Comment: Please add @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mGoogleClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
    mGoogleClient.disconnect();
}

Comment: Please refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105118/already-managing-a-googleapiclient-with-id-0-in-fragment

Comment: but i am using appcompactactivity when i use the above code the app gets closed and it shows cannot use fragment activity