# Android crash due to GoogleApiClient

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

Essentially I am trying to close the GoogleApiClient when I pause or finish the fragment as it is crashing when I go back into said fragment.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(),this)
                .build();
}

@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.example.conornaylor.fyp, PID: 7055
>                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already managing a GoogleApiClient
>   with id 0
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbau.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.example.conornaylor.fyp.event.CreateEventFragment.onViewCreated(CreateEventFragment.java:164)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1343)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:725)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0 In FRAGMENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105118/already-managing-a-googleapiclient-with-id-0-in-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by calling mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage() in the onPause method  of the fragment.